# How do I get the gradient of the loss at a TensorFlow variable?

Tags: tensorflow

The feature I'm after is to be able to tell what the gradient of a given variable is with respect to my error function given some data.

One way to do this would be to see how much the variable has changed after a call to train, but obviously that can vary massively based on the learning algorithm (for example it would be almost impossible to tell with something like RProp) and just isn't very clean.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the solution to your question work also if I want to see/inspect the gradients as training progresses?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The [`tf.gradients()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) function allows you to compute the symbolic gradient of one tensor with respect to one or more other tensors—including variables.  Consider the following simple example:

```
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
var = tf.Variable(...)              # Must be a tf.float32 or tf.float64 variable.
loss = some_function_of(var, data)  # some_function_of() returns a `Tensor`.

var_grad = tf.gradients(loss, [var])[0]
```

You can then use this symbolic gradient to evaluate the  gradient in some specific point (data):

```
sess = tf.Session()

var_grad_val = sess.run(var_grad, feed_dict={data: ...})
```

Comment: What if you want to use the gradient in conjunction with a built-in training algorithm like `GradientDescentOptimizer` or `AdagradOptimizer`? I want to avoid having to compute the gradient of the network twice.

Comment: The `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` class (and related `Optimizer` classes) call `tf.gradients()` internally. If you want to access the gradients that are computed for the optimizer, you can call `optimizer.compute_gradients()` and `optimizer.apply_gradients()` manually, instead of calling `optimizer.minimize()`.

Comment: @mrry: Just to clarify though, `symbolic` gradient here is just an un-evaluated tensor and not the actual symbolic gradient, i.e. symgrad(x^2) = 2*x . Is there any way to get this without looking at the tensorboard?

Comment: does this work also if I want to see the gradients as training progresses? You said numerical derivatives which makes me uneasy that this is inefficient or not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Pinocchio: I think by numeric derivative be just meant the derivative evaluated at the given point.

Answer (score 11):

In TensorFlow 2.0 you can use [`GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) to achieve this. `GradientTape` records the gradients of any computation that happens in the context of that. Below is an example of how you might do that.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Here goes the neural network weights as tf.Variable
x = tf.Variable(3.0)

# TensorFlow operations executed within the context of
# a GradientTape are  recorded for differentiation 
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  # Doing the computation in the context of the gradient tape
  # For example computing loss
  y = x ** 2 

# Getting the gradient of network weights w.r.t. loss
dy_dx = tape.gradient(y, x) 
print(dy_dx)  # Returns 6
```

Comment: does `x` need to be a `Variable` given you're not explicitly mutating it here?