# Get "loss" function from a restored tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I have stored a Tensorflow model with the files .meta, .index, checkpoint, and .data-0001. I restore my graph and model using:

```
model = tf.train.import_meta_graph("models/model.meta")
model.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("models/"))
```

I restored some variables like weights and bias but I also need to restore the loss function. My model is using `nce_loss`.
Essentially, I want to get the gradient for my loss function given a certain input where I don't have to redefine the loss variables just call the operation from the restored version. So:

```
loss = graph.get_operation_by_name("loss")
grads = tf.gradients(loss,loss.inputs)
```

And here I get the following error message:

```
File "/tmp/fgsm.py", line 114, in main
    grads = tf.gradients(loss,loss.inputs)
  File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 630, in gradients
    gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients)
  File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 675, in _GradientsHelper
    ys = ops.convert_n_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices(ys, name="y")
  File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1377, in convert_n_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices
    values=values, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=False)
  File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1348, in internal_convert_n_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices
    value, dtype=dtype, name=n, as_ref=as_ref))
  File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1307, in internal_convert_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices
    value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1146, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6168, in _operation_conversion_error
    name, as_ref))
TypeError: Can't convert Operation 'loss' to Tensor (target dtype=None, name='y_0', as_ref=False)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

so by switching to

```
loss = graph.get_tensor_by_name("loss:0")
```

I can successfully get my loss tensor. Now how do I get the gradient for the input given the restored loss function?
 `nce_loss` has an "input" parameter and I want to calculate the gradient given the loss function and the input parameter. How can I use `tf.gradients` for this? When I do `tf.gradients(loss,loss.inputs)` I get an error

`AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'inputs'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are retrieving tensors from tensorflow, you must index them. In your code:

```
loss = graph.get_operation_by_name("loss")
grads = tf.gradients(loss,loss.inputs)
```

As the error states you are retrieving the operation of loss not its output tensor. To retrieve its tensor you can index the operation like so:

```
loss = graph.get_operation_by_name("loss:0")
grads = tf.gradients(loss,loss.inputs)
```

Comment: When I defined the loss in the original model, I named it simply "loss". Do I need to change the naming convention or is that ok?

Comment: please check my post for added details of my follow up question.

Comment: @Mnemosyne No need to change the naming convention when building the graph, the indexing is only for retrieval

Comment: To get the gradient, you must feed in a placeholder tensor and compute the variable see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226428/how-do-i-get-the-gradient-of-the-loss-at-a-tensorflow-variable