# How to compute gradient of output wrt input in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I have a trained Tensorflow 2.0 model (from tf.keras.Sequential()) that takes an input layer with 26 columns (X) and produces an output layer with 1 column (Y).

In TF 1.x I was able to calculate the gradient of the **output with respect to the input** with the following:

```
model = load_model('mymodel.h5')
sess = K.get_session()
grad_func = tf.gradients(model.output, model.input)
gradients = sess.run(grad_func, feed_dict={model.input: X})[0]
```

In TF2 when I try to run tf.gradients(), I get the error:

> RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.

In the question [In TensorFlow 2.0 with eager-execution, how to compute the gradients of a network output wrt a specific layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478454/in-tensorflow-2-0-with-eager-execution-how-to-compute-the-gradients-of-a-networ), we see an answer on how to calculate gradients with respect to intermediate layers, but I don't see how to apply this to gradients with respect to the inputs. On the [Tensorflow help](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) for tf.GradientTape, there are examples with calculating gradients for simple functions, but not neural networks.

How can **tf.GradientTape** be used to calculate the gradient of the output with respect to the input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In TensorFlow 2.0 with eager-execution, how to compute the gradients of a network output wrt a specific layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478454/in-tensorflow-2-0-with-eager-execution-how-to-compute-the-gradients-of-a-networ)

Comment: @LongNguyen - No, it doesn't. I've already linked to that answer in my question and explained why it doesn't answer it.

Comment: This should answer your questions. But this is for a very simple function. However the comments should guide you on how you can adapt this to a neural network. If you still have trouble, let me know so I can edit the answer to suit your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226428/how-do-i-get-the-gradient-of-the-loss-at-a-tensorflow-variable/58314728#58314728

Comment: @thushv89 - Thanks for the link. I've looked through that example, but haven't been successful trying to adapt it to my question. I've tried:

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    preds = model(model.input)
    dy_dx = tape.gradient(preds,tf.convert_to_tensor(X))

  but this gives the error: "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 0 for 'Equal_1' (op: 'Equal') with input shapes: [2], [0]."

Comment: I'll have a look and post the answer here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work in TF2:

```
inp = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=(25, 120)), dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    preds = model(inp)

grads = tape.gradient(preds, inp)
```

Basically you do it the same way as TF1, but using `GradientTape`.

Comment: Thanks! This works (I just had to change the input shape to be "size=(120,26)" since I have 26 input columns). The crux was using tf.Variable() to convert the data (X) from numpy to a tf variable (inp). I had tried tf.convert_to_tensor(), but this didn't work.

Comment: Do you know 1) Why do you need to use tf.Variable() rather than inputting a numpy array directly? 2) Why do you call model(inp) rather than model.predict(inp)? (What's the different between model(X) and model.predict(X)?)

Comment: I have no idea about variables, but model(x) and model.predict(x) do not do the same, predict works with numpy arrays, while model(x) does a symbolic computation that tensorflow can differentiate.

Comment: do you know how to compute every grad in a (x,y)-batch,but not use for loop?use for loop is too slow.

Comment: @Song Please ask your own question with all the details.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you're looking for. This will give the gradients of the output w.r.t. the inputs.

```
# Whatever the input you like goes in as the initial_value
x = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=(25, 120)), dtype=tf.float32)
y_true = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(25,10))

print(model.output)
print(model.predict(x))
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  pred = model.predict(x)

grads = tape.gradients(pred, x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. Is this for TF2? When I try this (changing x and y_true to match my data), tf.gradients() results in the error "RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead." I suspect that rather than using tf.gradients(), we need to use tape.gradient().

Comment: Edited to use `tape.gradient`.

Comment: do you know how to compute every grad in a (x,y)-batch,but not use for loop?use for loop is too slow.

Comment: @Song, can you give an example. If I'm not mistaken, grads will be of size whatever your `x` is (meaning you'd have gradients for each sample in the batch). And how did you use a for loop?

Comment: @thushv89  yes,the gradtape returns one gradient even x contains many examples,sometimes i need to compute every grad for every example in a mini-batch.then i can clip the gradient the grad.      It seem that the gradtape always return only one grad,so it seems there is not good idea except a for loop.  so does pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

In the above case, we should use `tape.watch()`

```
for (x, y) in test_dataset:
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(x)

        pred = model(x)

grads = tape.gradient(pred, x)
```

but the grads will just have the grads of the inputs

The following method is better, you can **use model to predict the prediction results and compute the loss, then use the loss to calculate the grads of all trainable variables**

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = model(x, training=True)
    loss = loss_function(y, predictions)
grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
```