# Having trouble getting the gradient on with a given model on Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

For some purpose, I'm trying to do gradient descent on a randomly initialized vector (numpy array) as input while given a simple model.

This is the summary of my model:

[image: Given Model]

And this is the algorithm I'm trying to realize (paper linked below):

[image: Algorithm]

Which is simply doing gradient descent on a random input (with shape `(512,)` in this case) minimizing a custom loss (which is the square of a certain output neuron).

The idea is quite simple, but I'm having a hard time implementing it.

The following are functions I looked up and tried, but the output turns out to be a list of `(512, 512)` arrays instead of one `(512,)`. Also, `tf.reduce_mean()` is not what I intended to use, but it's relatively a small problem here.

```
    def loss_fn(model, inputs, targets):
        error = model(inputs) - targets
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error))
    
    def gradients(model, inputs, targets):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss_value = loss_fn(model, inputs, targets)
        return (tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables), loss_value)

    for e in range(epochs):
        gradient, loss = gradients(model, x, y)
        x = x - learning_rate * gradient
        print('epoch', e, 'loss', loss)
```

Can anyone point out which part I'm doing wrong?

I assume the shapes of tensors are all messed up here, but I really have no clue where and how to start fixing it.

Sorry for this naive question, I hope I described it well though. Thanks in advance.

[Paper: Trojaning Attack on Neural Networks](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2782&context=cstech)

Edit: Apparently I did not explain well enough.

The problem is here:

```
gradient, loss = gradients(model, x, y)
```

`gradients()` isn't giving the expected results.

Expected: return `int, np.array(shape=(512,))` on parameters `model, np.array(shape=(512,)) np.array(shape=(10,))`

What I got:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_5 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (512,)
```

Comment: You need to explain the problem, to me it is not clear what the problem is, what output is incorrect? Are you sure you are taking gradient with respect to the correct variables?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Edited. Sorry for not explaining well enough.

Comment: You are computing gradients with respect to model parameters, while your image suggests that you want gradients of the loss/cost with respect to your model inputs, so the output is unexpected because the wrong gradient is being computed.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks, I actually found one of your answers found here to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145221/how-to-compute-gradient-of-output-wrt-input-in-tensorflow-2-0 Really appreciated.