# Is there a faster way to compute gradients of output wrt inputs in keras/tensorflow (graph mode)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

It seems that the standard way to compute the gradient of the output of a keras model with respect to the input variables (for example, see [How to compute gradient of output wrt input in Tensorflow 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145221/how-to-compute-gradient-of-output-wrt-input-in-tensorflow-2-0)) is something like the following:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    preds = model(input)    
grads = tape.gradient(preds, input)
```

However, this is **extremely** slow when the input tensor is large (e.g. ten million observations of 500 input variables). The above code also does not seem to use the GPU at all.

When training the model using `model.fit(input)`, it runs on the GPU and is super fast, despite the large input tensor.

Is there any way to speed up the gradient calculation?

#### About version

I am running Python 3.8 and Tensorflow v2.9.1. For various reasons I can only run in graph mode--i.e., tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: model.fit is fast due to batching, you will clog any device with such a large tensor.

Comment: Thanks. How should I implement efficient batching for the gradient calculation? Using loops in python is also extremely slow.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are not handling batches, or at least this is what I understand from the info you have given.

According to the [`fit()`](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method) documentation, the function takes an argument `batch_size`, which defaults to 32:

> batch_size: Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update. If
> unspecified, batch_size will default to 32

However with gradient tape, you have to manually handle batches. The `input`, in your code must be a batch.

This means you should have something like the following code:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for batch in range(num_batch):
        images = x_train[batch * batch_size: (batch + 1) * batch_size]
        labels = y_train[batch * batch_size: (batch + 1) * batch_size]
        # calling the tape on single batch
        step(model, images)

@tf.function
def step(model, x):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        preds = model(x)    
    grads = tape.gradient(preds, x)
```

Also in order to improve performances, I've wrapped the gradient tape inside a `tf.function`. This decorator is basically responsible, on first call, for compiling a static graph of the operations inside the function that it decorates. This way subsequent calls can be a lot faster. Here to know more about [better performance with tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am indeed not handling batches in the gradient computation. But wouldn't the difference be that the batches in model.fit run in parallel while a loop in python would not? Or does tf.function take care of that?

Comment: As far as I know not even the batches in `model.fit` are handled in parallel: the data inside a batch is. If you think about it, it would mean that all your train data would fit into memory, which is almost always not possible, and would make the purpose of batches pointless. Your tape is slow because your CPU is overloaded with data. Also during the training phase are computed and stored the labels-predictions errors. Storing the errors for your whole dataset at each epoch is quite inefficient. Hope this clarifies. Also I've added some info about `tf.function` inside the answer.

Comment: just a note: the fact that something runs on CPU or GPU is based on the policy of TF, not on "graph or not", his loop is slow because as ClaudiaR explained, you are not taking advantage of TF Graph, which is built the first time, and then reused to optimize the process... just pay attention that is build for every input shape/type, so be carefull, otherwise the profiling will just slow down you training loop (in other words, graph are used to "remember" how to calculate the gradient, instead of discovering it again every time)

Comment: Thanks ClaudiaR, I will give your suggestion with tf.function a try.

Comment: Alright, let me know how it goes. If this solves your issue please consider accepting the answer and / or upvoting